# Unable to define different CSS styles in buttons having different classes?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 different buttons in my site, and I want both of them to look different. I can't figure out how to get it to work.

Right now, my CSS code is:

```
input.button{ }
```

But if I have two buttons and I need them both to have different colors, then I do this:

```
<input type=button class="button1">
<input type button class="button2">
```

I don't know how to link this to CSS. I tried this but nothing happened:

```
input.button.button1{}
input.button.button2{}
```

Of course, I haven't added anything in the curly brackets, but I do add them and it doesn't seem to work. Though, if I remove one of it, and then also delete the ".button1", then they seem to work fine.  But again I can't have different properties for different buttons then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want this:

```
<input type="button" class="button button1" />
<input type="button" class="button button2" />
```

CSS

```
input.button { /* Shared styles here */ }
input.button1 { /* Button 1 specific styles here */ }
input.button2 { /* Button 2 specificstyles here */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to identify the class.

```
.button1 { foreground-color: red; }
.button2 { foreground-color: green; }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use just

```
.button1{}

.button2{}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try this to define your css classes:

`input .button1{...}`
`input .button2{...}`

Basically you can define CSS based on tag name, or element ID or class, or combinations of these 3. 'Button' has no place in your code because it's only a value of one of the attributes of the input tag.

Answer (score 0):

For this markup:

```
<input type="button" class="button1" value="one">
<input type="button" class="button2" value="two">
```

This CSS will result in different colors:

```
input.button1 { color: red; }
input.button2 { color: blue;}
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KVJgf/).

Be sure to clean up the errors in your CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

two points here, firstly you are failing to acutally define your buttons in your css, to define a type in css you do it like this:

```
input[type="button"]
```

secondly you have a html error there, this:

```
<input type button class="button2">
```

should be this:

That all done, yout css will look like:

```
input[type="button"].button1{}

input[type="button"].button2{}
```

if you dont need to be this specific you could alternatively just do:

```
.button1 {}

.button2 {}
```